# posting html form to mysql db and avoiding database attacks

Tags: php, mysql

I had a question to clarify the best method for taking form data and writing it to a mysql database in the safest way to prevent database attacks while also stripping html tags.  Below I have a function called form_write that does this and then I use it in my code when declaring each of the post form variables.

```
function form_write($string)
  {
     return mysql_real_escape_string(strip_html_tags($string));
  }

 $name = form_write($_POST['name']);
 $email = form_write($_POST['email']);
 ...etc
```

Would be grateful if anyone could take a look and let me know if I am on the right track or if there is a better way to be doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, stripping the tags and escaping the input makes it safe. Later you can add an extra validation layer to input variables. For example to validate the e-mail, you can use:

```
if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid e-mail address');
}
```

PHP has a lot of filters, see [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and the [list of filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php).

Comment: thank you for the extra info.  i haven't used exceptions to validate--just my own php code.  i'll check them out

Comment: Well, the important part in this snippet is the filter_var() function which validates the input. Exception is just a way to raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes **strip_tags()** is good and also you can use **preg_match()** to match whether entered email address is actually email address. And i recommend you to use **trim()** [which trims white space at the begining and ending].

> function form_write($string)
>
> {
>
> return mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($string)));
>
> }
>
> $name = form_write($_POST['name']);

I'm new here and if you think my answer is good. I would appreciate if you vote up.

Regards Venkat.